# Simple Select with where and offset fetch clause not working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to select rows with `where` condition and will need pagination. So I have added `Fetch` with `offset`[to make it dynamic] clause but then it gives this error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended Position: 414

My Query:

```
SELECT
    up.NAME upozilaName_bn,
       up.id upozila,
    dis.NAME districtName_bn,
       dis.id district,
    dv.NAME divisionName_bn,
       dv.id division,
    w.COUNTER_TYPE, w.COUNTER_ID,
    w.STATUS
FROM X w
left join  Y up
    ON w.UPOZILA = up.ID
left JOIN Z dis
    ON w.DISTRICT = dis.id
left join  P dv
    ON w.DIVISION = dv.ID
where 1=1  order by upozilaName_bn asc OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Without `FFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` this, it is okay! 
I searched for that error: `933`, but no help found.
Oracle version: 11.2g

Comment: The syntax is available starting in Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` is available from Oracle 12c.

Instead, you need to perform your query and order the data; then generate a row number for the ordered rows; and finally filter on those row numbers. These steps need to take place in the correct order in nested sub-queries:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT up.NAME AS upozilaName_bn,
           up.id AS upozila,
           dis.NAME AS districtName_bn,
           dis.id AS district,
           dv.NAME AS divisionName_bn,
           dv.id AS division,
           w.COUNTER_TYPE,
           w.COUNTER_ID,
           w.STATUS
    FROM X w
    left join  Y up ON w.UPOZILA = up.ID
    left JOIN  Z dis ON w.DISTRICT = dis.id
    left join  P dv ON w.DIVISION = dv.ID
    order by upozilaName_bn asc
  ) T
)
WHERE  rn BETWEEN 2 AND 11;
```

Comment: just clarification, in second `select`, `t` meant to be `T` set as alias end of the query , right?

Comment: @user404 Yes, identifiers in Oracle are case-insensitive so the table/sub-query alias `T` and it's use in the `SELECT` clause `t.*` are the same thing and they don't need to be the same case; you can of course change them to be the same case if you prefer but you're already using `up.id` and `up.ID` and its the same principal as there.  (You can make identifiers case-sensitive if you wrap them in double-quotes; but using double-quotes is not good practice as you have to use the same case everywhere the identifier is used).